# Getting error while using json and simple json in .py file

Tags: json, python-3.x, import, attributeerror, simplejson

When I used `import json` getting error as `ImportError: cannot import name 'JSONDecodeError' from 'json' (unknown location)`

After few research i changed as

```
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ValueError:
    import json
```

now new error is `AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'dumps'`
Can anyone help me to understand that what's happening here? and I'm using Python 3.9V

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled Json extension package from my pip list and it worked without any mentioned error.